# Como puedo comparar el valor de un choiceField en django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Perdon si no soy claro, no se como formaular la pregunta, soy nuevo con django.
La idea que tengo es hacer un if en el template que me muestre una opcion de editar area si el area es igual a 'None'
tengo un choiceField con las distintas areas y una señal que cuando se cree un usuario se cree una area inicializada en 'None'
Lo que no se como hacer en el template para preguntar si el area es igual a 'None'

```
 {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  {% if user.area == 'None'  %}

  <div class="notification {{ messages.tags }}" id="usuario">
    <a href="{% url 'editArea' %}">Editar</a>
  </div>

  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

No se contra que tengo que comparar el user.area ya que no se que tipo de dato es

Modelo:

class Area(models.Model):

```
areas = (('None','None'),('Administracion','Administracion'),('Sistemas','Sistemas'),('Imagen','Imagen'),('RRHH','RRHH'), ('Abastecimiento','Abastecimiento'),
('Mantenimiento','Mantenimiento'),('Gerentes','Gerentes'), ('Compras','Compras'), ('Legales','Legales'), ('Otra','Otra'))

user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='area', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
area = models.CharField('Area', max_length=25, choices=areas, null=False)


def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f'{self.area}'
```

Forms:

class EditArea(forms.ModelForm):

```
areas = (('Administracion','Administracion'),('Sistemas','Sistemas'),('Imagen','Imagen'),('RRHH','RRHH'), ('Abastecimiento','Abastecimiento'),
('Mantenimiento','Mantenimiento'),('Gerentes','Gerentes'), ('Compras','Compras'), ('Legales','Legales'), ('Otra','Otra'))
area = forms.ChoiceField(choices=areas)


class Meta:
    model = Area
    fields = ['area']
```

Alguna recomendacion?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Como estás haciéndolo desde los templates, puedes hacerlo de varias maneras, por ejemplo:

```
{% if user.area == None %}

{% if user.area is None %}

{% if not user.area %}
```

Comment: las 2 primeras no me funcionan. Nunca entra en el if, no lo puedo comparar con None, ni 'None', ni '', ni ninguna otra opcion como str o variable.
Pero si me troma el if con True o False

Comment: Estas seguro que tu valor es None y no esta en blanco? que pasa si imprimes en el template {{ user.area }}

Comment: Me dice None si lo imprimo. O el valor de user.área, ya sea Administración o cualquiera. Y con {% if user.area %} o con su negación si me funciona